# Pulling out some text from a giant HTML file using Nokogiri/xpath

Tags: html, regex, url, scrape

I am scraping a website and am trying to pull out certain elements from the HTML. In the sites I am scraping, there are **script tags** with a bunch of info in them however, there is one part inside these tags that I am interested in. The line basically looks like:

```
'image':'http://ut5.example.com/t/231/3_b_643435.jpg',
```

With some stuff above and below it. Now, this is **different for each page source** except for obviously the domain and some of the subfolders that store the images.

How would I go about looking through the source for this specific line, and cutting out just the URL? I would need to use regular expressions I feel as the URLs are dynamic.

The "gsub" method does something similar to what I want to search for, with its ability to use /regex/. But, I am not wanting to replace anything, I just want to find that URL in the source code using a /regex/ and copy it.

Comment: Can you put an example of what's supposed to be the result? Is it `'image': 'image.jpg'`?

Comment: I would like to be able to just pull out the URL. The "gsub" method somewhat does what I want it to do, search for a /regex/...however, I don't want to replace anything, I want to just copy it into a new string or something.

Comment: So you just want to extract `3_b_643435.jpg` from the above example and put it in a variable, am I right?

Comment: Yes, but also the preceeding URL. So `http://ut5.example.com/t/231/3_b_643435.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to you comments, this is what you're looking for I guess

```
var regex = /http.+/;
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/Km9ZB/

Comment: Works great, I had the regex setup. I was trying to use "scan" but "match" works great! Thank you!